# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' in anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, keras, graph, anaconda

I am getting an error here:

```py
from keras.applications import VGG16

modelvgg =VGG16(include_top=True,weights=None)
modelvgg.load_weights("Data/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
modelvgg.summary()
```

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your import it should be:

`from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16`

Check the documentation [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/) and remember to add 'tensorflow' at the beginning of the imports.